# How to get a more detailed Google Analytics report about a campaign

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, campaigns

I'm running an e-commerce website and have a featured product block on the home page.

When the banner is generated, the URL is dynamically assembled using the [Google Campaign URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) guidelines:

```
?utm_source=homepage&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=MSI+N660+GAMING+GTX+660+2GB+Desktop+Graphics+Card&utm_campaign=featured%20product
```

In other words:

- Campaign source is: homepage
- Campaign medium is: banner
- Campaign Content is: MSI N660 Gaming GTX 660 2GB Desktop Graphics Card
- Campaign Name is: featured product

The problem is Google Analytics seems to group these together regardless of the content, which is not ideal because I'm trying to track each featured product's efficacy separately.

If I navigate to Acquisition → Campaigns → featured product

I can now see a single item under the Source/Medium column, which in this case is `homepage/banner`.

I was under the impression that if I click onto the `homepage / banner` option, it should show me the `Campaign Contents`, but it doesn't. It simply displays homepage / banner again, this time greyed out & not click-able and I cannot see the contents.

[image]

Is there any way to workaround this - or am I doing something incorrectly.

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to see - can you not achieve that by adding a second dimension to that view that your screenshot shows?

Comment: @zigojacko I'm trying to see the campaign contents, in this case the MSI N660 for example so I can differentiate between the different featured product clicks. I can't seem to find contents as a secondary dimension under Acquisition.

Comment: @moose Yes, you're doing wrong ;) Add a second dimension "Ad Content" (ga:adContent) in basic Acquisition > Campaigns report.

Comment: @jakub.kowalik - thanks, exactly what I was looking for. If you can post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept & up-vote.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the 'content' dimension to the secondary source within GA campaign section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is Select "Ad Content" as you secondary dimension. Below is a snapshot:

[image]

Also, Have you thought about using Google Tag Manager and dataLayers to do this? Its much more efficient. You can use HTML5 data-attributes or you can setup a custom dimension.